# Dart async void

Tags: dart

Why we can have `void myFunc() async{}` function? Why `void` returning is acceptable
Actually every `async` is a `Future` and I except the `Future<void>` returning value

Comment: FWIW, you can enable the `avoid_void_async` linter rule if you want it to be a warning when you do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason:

```dart
void log(String message) {
  getLogger.then((logger) {
    logger.write(message);
  });
}
```

would be allowed. It does something asynchronous, but doesn't return a future.

Sometimes you just want to do something which involves waiting for an asynchronous function, while not actually needing, or wanting, anyone to wait for you.

I'd be happier if `void foo() async { ... }` didn't return a future at all, but as it is, a `void` function may return any value, it's the caller's responsibility not to use that value for anything. That's what a `void` return type means.

The biggest issue with a `void` return type on an `async` function is that it might hide an easily made mistake. If the author intended to return a `Future<void>`, and just forgot to write the `Future`, then it won't be caught locally. You won't notice it until someone tries to do an `await` on the returned value and gets a warning about using the value of a `void` expression. So, do be careful.